# Does 2 additional tables better than one with meta?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

Have a question about architecture: I have 2 subjects, `DocumentLetter` and `DocumentOther`, both should be approved by managers.

What would be better: to use 2 additional models `DocumentLetterApprove` and `DocumentOtherApprove` with entity relations, OR one additional table without relations but contains info about model identity (columns ModelName and ModelID)?

Or another example, attachments for different documents.

Letter, contract - 2 different tables and each should have own attachment.

I can use additional table for each model (for letter and for contract) or create one table with fields field ModelName and ModelID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would favor keeping the separate entities /w the relationships if there is any possibility that the related entities (approvals) could be in any way different depending on what they are applied to. I avoid ambiguously linked tables unless they represent a large 1 to many entity that might be associated to one of a number of other entities.

The problem with using something like a "ParentType" + "ParentId" is that you cannot leverage any form of FK constraint between the related tables. This also means you cannot leverage EF relationships given there will probably be times loading one of documents and wanting to know if it is approved and details from the approval.

If an Approval for the different document types is expected to be identical then I would sooner declare a common Approval table/Entity and put an ApprovalId on each of the document type tables to establish a many-to-1 relationship from the document to the approval.

If an approval is identical and can form a many to many, then a suitable many-to-many relation table DocumentLetter - DocumentLetterApproval (FKs) - Approval (Approval details) can be employed.

If a Letter approval vs. other approval could be different then: DocumentLetter - DocumentLetterApproval (Approval details)

Design decisions like this usually come from considerations around DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). What advice I can give is that KISS (Keep It Stupidly Simple) should trump DRY, and that DRY should only apply to logic/structure that is proven to be identical. (not merely expected to be identical, or worse, expected to be similar) DRY should be a re-factoring consideration for constant improvement, not an up-front design decision. Coding for DRY too early ends up costing you time when you paint yourself into corners. By keeping code fluid these relationships can be proven, then if they are proven to be identical, re-factored into a single entity. Time is still spent re-factoring, but re-factoring to make code structure better rather than making code worse when having to work around design assumptions.

An example where i might consider an ambiguous loosely linked linked table would be something like File Attachments. I might have several entities that can hold references to 1 or more attachments. Attachments are not something I would need to link to often, but rather through an explicit action that I could fire off an additional query for anyways since I'm not about to pre-load attachment details when loading a document. In this case an attachment table might have a ParentType and ParentId indexed so that I can quickly get details for a particular document or other entity. I would never try to do something like `Context.Documents.Include(x => x.Attachments)` or the like, there would be no such reference available. Attachments would always be accessed by single document so I would resort to `Context.Attachments.Where(x => x.ParentType == ParentTypes.DocumentLetter && x.ParentId == documenLetterId).ToList();`

I have experience working on systems that were designed *solely* with these types of ambiguously linked tables. They are not only extremely slow as they scale to any reasonable size, but they are also extremely error prone as systems evolve and the nature of the relationships change. Records have a tendency to get out of sync with the expected rules.